# Seleccionar elementos del dom

Tags: javascript, css

```
const abrirMenu = (s) => document.querySelector(s);
```

Estoy comenzando en el mundo del diseño web y me tope con un tutorial en ingles donde estan creando una menu hamburguesa responsive y me tope con esa variable adentro tiene una funcion de flecha pero me pregunto porque pasa el parametro y luego lo pide en el querySelector de verdad no lo tiendo

Comment: Si no envías parámetro a `.querySelector()` ¿qué va a seleccionar?, lo mismo si la función flecha no recibe el parámetro.

Comment: `abrirMenu` en este caso es una funcion, que al pasarle un valor (un selector CSS como por ejemplo `.menu`) retorna el primer elemento referenciado por el selector. SI proporcionas mas lineas del codigo en contexto podria quedar mas claro como se usa.

Comment: Qué es lo que no entiendes, ¿la función flecha (arrow function)? ¿la función querySelector? En caso de la segunda, la respuesta te la ha dado @Triby